# Request a letter verifying international health coverage and benefits from BlueShield BlueCross for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, health, tips-and-tricks, insurance

Per [Schengen visa requirements](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810) (article 15) any traveler must have a medical insurance with 30000 EUR coverage. The permanent resident in the US has BlueShield/Bluecross coverage with the  [BlueCard Worldwide® Program](https://employer.carefirst.com/carefirst-resources/pdf/bluechoice-advantage-member-handbook-bok5266.pdf). A letter is needed stating that the said person has coverage and appropriate benefits.

A call to Bluecard resulted in nothing. They do not know what is this all about as majority of their customers are US citizens, not permanent residents.

Additionally, I found information about a [Canadian person](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50005/use-insurance-provided-by-employer-when-applying-for-a-schengen-visa) that was able to request a letter from HR and about a [possiblity to get the similar letter](https://www.aigtravelguard.net/mastercard/Default.aspx?IdLanguage=1&mod=faq) from the credit card you used to buy your ticket.

How to obtain one? Does this coverage verification letter has some name one can refer to? Whom do I need to contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Living in the US, with a Green Card, I had to do the same thing for visas some months ago [you again? me again!].

Fortunately, our HR department was able to provide this (by calling the Health Insurance and getting it - the letter was from the Health insurance).

Note that the letter did *not* fulfill the technical requirements (naming the insured amount and so on), but they told me it would be fine, and *it was fine*.

That does not mean something like that will work for you, but it probably would.

Comment: It may be different from one Schengen country's consular service to the next.

Comment: My HR said they provided such letter ~4years ago. I will let you know how it worked out